How do I prevent font class names being obfuscated?
I have an application that includes a number of ttf fonts and I get the font names using the following code:
            val fontClass = R.font::class.java
            val fields = fontClass.declaredFields
            val fonts: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
            fonts.add("")
            for(font in fields) {
                try {
                    fonts.add(font.name)
                } catch(e: Exception) {
                    // Do nothing - just ignore.
                }
            }


However, when I obfuscate the code using minifyEnabled = true the fonts can no longer be found as the font class has been renamed.
How do I use proguard rules to prevent the class and the font resource names from being modified so the application can still reference them?
The only way I can get the fonts to be listed is to set minifyEnabled to false.
